# C++: tall class hierarchies

Tags: c++, class, inheritance, height, hierarchy

What are the run time disadvantages of having a *tall* class hierarchy?

Let's call `H` the *height* of the hierarchy (ie: how many classes are traversed to go from the base class to a leaf).

`dynamic_cast` will cost more: it costs `O(H)`.

Are there other operators or language features suffering?

Comment: Do developers count as 'operators'? They'll be suffering :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The main problem will be maintainability. A deep class hierarchy is probably not modeled correctly. Anything more than 3-4 levels should get you alerted. You are probably deriving from concrete classes, something you should never do ([Liskov Substitution principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle) doesn't allow this). Refactoring will be difficult if your base classes are riddled with `virtual` functions (I mean **not** pure).

Split your base classes into several different interfaces ([Interface Segregation](http://www.objectmentor.com/resources/articles/isp.pdf)). Prefer composition over inheritance (GoF [fundamental rule](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Design_Patterns_%28book%29) of software design).

Personal advice: Try to program without `dynamic_cast`. I was able to program completely without `dynamic_cast` when I was a C++ developer. I used design patterns where appropriate, factories, [visitors](http://beta.boost.org/doc/libs/1_44_0/doc/html/variant/tutorial.html#variant.tutorial.basic), etc. Life was much more simple without casts :-).

Good luck!

Comment: LSP doesn’t explicitly forbid deriving from concrete classes (but it’s very hard to do this meaningfully without violating LSP). But it’s usually (always?) a bad idea. Still, a **very good** answer.

Comment: I of course agree. I avoid using `dynamic_cast`, but am trying to find out what C++ features cost depends on a hierarchy height. It's also uncommon (and bad practice) having _tall_ classes, unless you're playing a lot with templates; look for example at [boost::operators](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_38_0/libs/utility/operators.htm).

Comment: @peoro: boost::operators and other meta-template programming technics (like type lists) are quite a corner case. Note (for example) that boost::operators have no `virtual` methods and cannot be used as a traditional base class. I would probably inherit them on the side (using multiple inheritance) since they are empty bases, we can hope for EBO here.

Answer (score 1):

All the operations can be implemented in O(1) time, and usually they all are, except `dynamic_cast`. The last one can be implemented in O(1) time for statically linked libraries, see [here](http://www.research.att.com/~bs/fdc_jcse.pdf).

Answer (score 0):

the construction and destruction of objects of leaf classes take longer, as all constructors in the hierarchy are called (from the base class down to the leaf class).

Comment: Hey, these can't be considered "overhead" since they are part of the functionality of the code!

Comment: I agree with @ybungalobill on this. The cost isn't different whether you're constructing base classed or, say, member objects, so this isn't cost introduced due to inheritance.

Comment: @ybungalobill: I guess this depend on whether or not your constructors are inlined or not. If like me you prefer not to inline them (makes changing them less painful), then this would be more costly simply because there would be more "calls" (which don't participate to the functionality).

Comment: @Matthieu: But they wouldn't be inlined either if they were constructing members instead of base classes, no? Look, however you design those sub-objects to relate to your class (bases, members, external objects, whatever), they _need to get constructed_. Stuffing them into a tall class hierarchy (a term I had never heard before, but which does make sense) won't change any of that. It's almost a pure compiler frontend issue. `struct X : Y {};` might generate exactly the same code as `struct X { Y y; };` (or `struct X {}; Y y;`, FTM). Which is, I think, the heart of ybungalobill's critique.